# SQL combine LIKE & AND & =

Tags: sql, equals, sql-like

```
var getData = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE exercise = " + exercise + " AND exerVariName LIKE '[A-Z]%' AND date >= '" + fromDate + "' AND date <= '" + toDate + "'";
```

I cant seem to figure out why the LIKE part in this line doesn't work! I found on w3schools that you can do LIKE '[a-z]%' if you want all values in that column. But it doesn't work. I don't get any errors but I don't get any results either!

I have this second line for when I dont want all, but a specific one (exerVariName), this one works. (I choose either a specific one or 'All' via a dropdown menu.)

```
var getDataS = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE exercise = " + exercise + " AND exerVariName = '" + exerVariName + "' AND date >= '" + fromDate + "' AND date <= '" + toDate + "'";
```

**UPDATE!**

I want to write out some data from the db just for view, so I select 'exercise' with radiobuttons, 'exerVariName' with a dropdown menu and 'fromDate/toDate' with a textbox!

```
<div>
    <select name="exerVariName">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        @foreach (var get in db.Query(getVariName)) {
            <option value="@get.exerVariName">@get.exerVariName</option> 
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

So I get the select option data from a database except the first one that I put there with "all" as the value.

Then I have this code: (thisData is put in the foreach)

```
var thisData = "";

if  (exerVariName == "all") {
    thisData = getData;
} else {
    thisData = getDataS;
}
```

So that if the select-option-dropdown value is the "all" one, thisData = getData which is this one with the LIKE, the point of this line is to choose everything in the column from the database which is why I choose all the letters (a-z).

```
var getData = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE exercise = " + exercise + " AND exerVariName LIKE '[A-Z]%' AND date >= '" + fromDate + "' AND date <= '" + toDate + "'";
```

And if I select something specific in the dropdown it will go to the ELSE part of the if statement and use this line

```
var getDataS = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE exercise = " + exercise + " AND exerVariName = '" + exerVariName + "' AND date >= '" + fromDate + "' AND date <= '" + toDate + "'";
```

If you need more info, please tell me!

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to do here? Do you want to match for the literal string `[A-Z]`, or do you want strings that start with a letter?

Comment: Side note: Your statement is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample data and what you were trying to retrieve/return from that result set based on the query you are trying to formulate. Leave out anything unrelated like date ranges if those date ranges are not part of what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Alright, I will update the question right now, give me a sec!

Comment: Yes.  Specifically a result that isn't being returned that you think should be would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the point of this line is to choose everything in the column from the database which is why I choose all the letters (a-z).
>
> `var getData = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE exercise = " + exercise + " AND exerVariName LIKE '[A-Z]%' AND date >= '" + fromDate + "' AND date <= '" + toDate + "'";`

I think you are overthinking this. If you want everything (ie. no filter on the column) then omit that part/filter on the clause completely.

```
"SELECT * FROM Test WHERE exercise = " + exercise + " AND date >= '" + fromDate + "' AND date <= '" + toDate + "'";
```

Finally this is vulnerable to sql injection attacks, you should use parameterized statements instead of string concatenation. If you update your question with the language I might be able to procure an example of a parameterized query in that language.

Comment: Holy f*ck, it just blew my mind how I never thought of that?? damn! Thank you! Also, I will take my time to learn some security, this page however is only for personal use! will only be on my local server for myself!

Comment: @PontusSvedberg - good deal. We all get that as programmers (or anyone probably) when you stare at a problem for too long :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get all test base on like then please use like this

```
var getData = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE exercise = " + exercise + " AND exerVariName LIKE '%' AND date >= '" + fromDate + "' AND date <= '" + toDate + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var getData = "SELECT * FROM Test WHERE exercise = " + exercise + " AND exerVariName NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%' AND date >= '" + fromDate + "' AND date <= '" + toDate + "'";
```